# Pandas: unable to detect duplicates from two columns

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I am trying to remove duplicates from two columns. As seen below, Alabama and Alaska.

[image]

However, when I query below, it does not detect the duplicates. Same when I use drop_duplicates(). I have checked that there are no white spaces as they have the same character length too. Does anyone know what's wrong?

[image]

**EDIT**: Added a sample code below. The result is the same, no white spaces, can't detect duplicates.

```
list1=['Alabama','Alabama','Alabama','Alabama','Alaska']
list2=['Alabama','Auburn','Florence','Jacksonville','Alaska']
df=pd.DataFrame(list1, columns=['States'])
df['Region']=pd.DataFrame(list2)

df.duplicated()
```

Comment: You'll need to post raw data and code in order for others to try to reproduce this, you posted an image which no one can copy, where there are no duplicates

Comment: Added a sample code! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) for comparing columns:

```
df[df['States'].ne(df['Region'])]
```

Timings:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [353]: %timeit (df[df['States'].ne(df['Region'])])
10 loops, best of 3: 23.7 ms per loop

In [354]: %timeit (df[df['States'] != df['Region']])
10 loops, best of 3: 88.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: Hi, I have checked... there are no white spaces~  Have added a sample code for people to try too~

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. I add another faster solution in larger dataframes.

Comment: oh that's cool~ will accept urs as the answer since its faster~ thank u

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to compare the columns directly which you can easily do using inequality:

```
In [93]:
df[df['States'] != df['Region']]

Out[93]:
    States        Region
1  Alabama        Auburn
2  Alabama      Florence
3  Alabama  Jacksonville
```

`duplicated` looks for duplicated values within a single column or all columns collectively, it fails here because 'Alabama' appears only once in a single row, if you had it appear on in multiple rows then it would have removed them

Note there is the built-in method [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) which means `not equal` to which is faster but possibly less readable

Comment: damn, thanks! why doesn't pandas drop_duplicates work though? any idea?

Comment: @Jake please my updated answer regarding `drop_duplicates`

Comment: ohh, ok~ thanks. U managed to described it very clearly~ Appreciate your help very much

Answer (score 1):

The pd.DataFrame.duplicated() method detects duplicated rows within the entire dataframe. However, it does not detect duplicated values within rows which is what you required.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to remove, you can get the index and delete it by the index

```
list1 = ['Alabama', 'Alabama', 'Alabama', 'Alabama', 'Alaska']
list2 = ['Alabama', 'Auburn', 'Florence', 'Jacksonville', 'Alaska']
df = pd.DataFrame(list1, columns=['States'])
df['Region'] = pd.DataFrame(list2)

index_list = df[df['States'] == df['Region']].index.tolist()
df = df.drop(df.index[index_list])

print(df)
```

the output is below

```
States        Region
1  Alabama        Auburn
2  Alabama      Florence
3  Alabama  Jacksonville
```

df.drop_duplicates worked row-wise, so if there is more than 1 row contain same value, it will be deleted
the example is below

before drop_duplicate

```
    States        Region
0  Alabama       Alabama
1  Alabama        Auburn
2  Alabama      Florence
3  Alabama  Jacksonville
4   Alaska        Alaska
5   Alaska        Alaska
6   Alaska        Alaska
```

the row 4,5,6 is exactly the same, so all row except row number 4 will be deleted, after drop_duplicates the df will look like this

```
States        Region
0  Alabama       Alabama
1  Alabama        Auburn
2  Alabama      Florence
3  Alabama  Jacksonville
4   Alaska        Alaska
```